# How to block rawgit.com to access my website server

Tags: .htaccess

I think my website is injected with some script that is using rawgit.com. Recently my website runs very slow with browser lower bar notification "Transferring data from rawgit.com.." or "Read rawgit.com"..." . I have never used RawGit to serve raw files directly from GitHub. I can see they are using https://cdn.rawgit.com/ domain to serve files.

I would like my website to block everything related to this domains, how can I achieve that ?

Comment: You are going about this problem in the wrong way. If you don't want rawgit.com to be loaded on your domain, you should find the source of this problem, not try to prevent the symptoms (e.g. a resource loading). Find the script or iframe or browser extension that is causing this.

Comment: Yes but first immediate step I think is to block it, it can take plenty of time to investigate the cause while the attacker (if any) can delete all my files.

Answer (score 0):

As I said in the comments, you are going about this problem in the wrong way. If your site already includes sources you do not recognise or allow, you are already compromised and your main focus should be on figuring out how you got compromised, and how much access an attacker may have gotten. Based on how much access they have gotten, you may need to scrap everything and restore a backup.

The safest thing to do is to bring the server offline while you investigate. Make sure that you still have access to the systems you need to access (e.g. ssh), but block any other remote ip. Just "blocking rawgit.com" blocks one of the symptoms you can see and allows an attacker to change their attack while you are fumbling with that.

I do not recommend to only block rawgit.com, not even when it's your first move to counter this problem, but if you want you can use the `Content-Security-Policy` header. You can whitelist the urls you do expect and thus block the urls you do not. See [mdn](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Security-Policy) for more information.